# Issue trying to tweet an image/video using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, twitter, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to make a twitter bot using Selenium, Chromedriver, and Python. Currently I am able to login and reach my timeline but I am unable to figure out how to tweet an image/video. I am able to tweet text perfectly fine but am unable to do so for image/video.

My current code is:

```
driver.get(WEBSITE)
element = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/input')))
element.send_keys(os.getcwd() + "/downloads/image.jpg")
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span/span')))
element.click()
```

I first try to find the input XPATH and the second one is clicking the tweet button. The current error is that when I try to search for the element to upload a file it is unable to find it and times out. How can I get the image/video uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload an image or video you should send that image / video file path to the input file.
Let's say you want to upload an image located on you computer in the following path:
"C:\Users\you_name\Downloads\IMG_20180906_184135.jpg"
The input element to send this path is located on twitter home page by the following XPath "//input[@accept]", so to upload this file you can do the following:

```
driver.get(WEBSITE)
input_xpath = "//input[@accept]"
image_path = "C:\Users\you_name\Downloads\IMG_20180906_184135.jpg"
input_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, input_xpath)))
input_element.send_keys(image_path)
```

That's it, no need for any additional clicks etc.

Comment: I'll try this and update you. Could you tell  me how you found that xpath?

Comment: Sure. I know it is an input element. Normally located somewhere near the element user clicks to to upload the file. I searched that specific page and found it. You can see that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading on Twitter is somewhat easy.

For some reason, you cannot upload by sending the media path to the input field nor can you upload through Twitter's API for free users.

One way to get the job done is;

```
import pyautogui  # pip install pyautogui (if not installed already)

add_photo_xpath: str = '//div[@aria-label="Add photos or video"]'

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, add_photo_xpath).click()
sleep(3)  # We give sleep to allow the upload modal window

pyautogui.write(f'"FileName.extension"')
pyautogui.press('enter')
```

For `pyautogui.write(f'"FileName.extension"')`, make sure you are in the directory where the media is located else it would not work. To make sure it always open up where your desired media is located, open up the folder like you want to upload first using the automated browser before running the script OR **alternatively you can send in the full path of the media *MAKING SURE THE PATH IS SHORT AS POSSIBLE (not sure, between 30-50 characters)***